# JQuery not hitting when using secondary class as selector

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

(Code below) Trying to get a hover effect on the text in a `div`. Using class selectors in `JQuery` and it's not hitting when I use `$('.abc')` but does work when I use `$('#top-nav-1')` - not sure why it can't be hit when I select it by the secondary class. I can go through and use all the `id`s, but I'd rather just use one `class` - after all, that's what they're for!

Thanks, in advance, for the input on this.

**HTML:**

```
<div id="top-nav-1" class-"container abc">The Text</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.container {
    color: black;
}
```

**JQuery:**

```
$('.abc').hover(function() {
    $(this).css('color','red'); 
});
```

fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/yB9Jq/

Comment: You have a typo: `class=`, not `class-` (`=` not `-`).

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a typo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a typo: `class=`, not `class-` (`=` not `-`).

Also, jQuery's [`.hover()`](http://api.jquery.com/hover/) takes two functions as arguments:

```
.hover( handlerIn(eventObject), handlerOut(eventObject) )
```

So an example would be:

```
$('.abc').hover(
  function() {
     $(this).css('color','red'); 
  },
  function() {
     $(this).css('color',''); 
  }
);
```

[Your fiddle, updated.](http://jsfiddle.net/yB9Jq/4/)

Comment: Thanks, fixed the typo. I knew it didn't make any sense. Too bad editor didn't mark syntax mark it.

Comment: Yeah, but it is not just the typo, the `.hover()` function takes two arguments and you were using just one.

Answer (score 0):

Your markup is incorrect. You need to have `class="container abc"` instead of `class-"container abc"`

```
<div id="top-nav-1" class="container abc">The Text</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/yB9Jq/1/